# Detecting support for a given JavaScript event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, progressive-enhancement

I'm interested in using the JavaScript hashchange event to monitor changes in the URL's fragment identifier.  I'm aware of [Really Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) and the jQuery plugins for this.  However, I've reached the conclusion that in my particular project it's not really worth the added overhead of another JS file.

What I would like to do instead is take the "progressive enhancement" route.  That is, I want to test whether the hashchange event is supported by the visitor's browser, and write my code to use it if it's available, as an enhancement rather than a core feature.  IE 8, Firefox 3.6, and Chrome 4.1.249 support it, and that accounts for about 20% of my site's traffic.

So, uh ... is there some way to test whether a browser supports a particular event?

Comment: FYI, the phrase you're looking for is not "progressive enhancement" but rather "graceful degradation". Progressive enhancement is when you make your website accessible to all users but add features to a more specific group of users (JavaScript-enabled, HTML5-supporting, etc). Graceful degradation is when you depend on certain functionality, but have a backup method if it is not supported by the client. Not that it really matters. :)

Comment: Hmm.  I would argue that "graceful degradation" means that a web site continues to function even when functionality it ordinarily relies on is unavailable.

By contrast, "progressive enhancement" is when a site enables extra features that it does not rely on, only when the user agent supports them.

I'm planning on writing this particular code in such a way that it does not modify the location.hash property at all unless the hashchange event is available.  So that's a progressive enhancement.

And yeah, not that it really matters -- they're just two sides of one coin.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, the best approach is not going through browser sniffing, Juriy Zaytsev ([@kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax)) made a really useful method for detecting event support:

```
var isEventSupported = (function(){
  var TAGNAMES = {
    'select':'input','change':'input',
    'submit':'form','reset':'form',
    'error':'img','load':'img','abort':'img'
  }
  function isEventSupported(eventName) {
    var el = document.createElement(TAGNAMES[eventName] || 'div');
    eventName = 'on' + eventName;
    var isSupported = (eventName in el);
    if (!isSupported) {
      el.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
      isSupported = typeof el[eventName] == 'function';
    }
    el = null;
    return isSupported;
  }
  return isEventSupported;
})();
```

Usage:

```
if (isEventSupported('hashchange')) {
  //...
}
```

This technique is now used in some libraries like [jQuery](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/support.js#L127).

Read more here:

- [Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing)

Comment: That's a very interesting method... I particularly like the extra check of seeing if `'return;`' gets converted to a function automatically.

Comment: This looks like the most robust method.  Thanks for posting it!

Comment: +1 for mentioning jQuery, [jQuery is really the best, it solves all kinds of browser problems and is good, as well](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: @BlueRaja, I'm only mentioning jQuery as a reference, that a serious library is relying on this technique.

Comment: Credit where it's due: Thank you @CMS for this trick! I used it to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086400/feature-detection-for-ability-to-drop-file-over-html-file-input/

Comment: This method does not work for the 'onhashchange' event. The function has a flaw in that it will miss any events that are attached to the window object only. Also, it does not make sense to add "'hashchange':'window'" to the list of TAGNAMES since a new window element cannot be created, I believe. With "isEventSupported('hashchange')" the createElement() function will return a div which won't have the onhashchange event as a property and so the test fails even though window.onhashchange might be true.

Comment: @CMS - You should add prefix checking as well

Comment: it returns false for `readystatechange` on Chrome even though it works

Comment: "Detecting event support without browser sniffing" Link now broken (404)

Answer (score 27):

The <s>Mozilla documentation</s> suggested the following:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}
```

This works in IE8 and the Chrome 5 beta too (I didn't test Chrome 4.1), and correctly fails in Opera and Safari.

Edit: the Mozilla page I linked to no longer contains any suggestions. I can't find any other Mozilla docs containing suggestions for event detection either.

Comment: Very elegant.  I may use a version of this modified with some ideas from the other answer that got posted.  Thanks.

Comment: @Keavon it works for me. But you have to use `"onclick"`. But also see the accepted answer and the blog it links to.

Comment: @mercator Ah, I forgot the `on` prefix, thanks. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modification of the [answer provided by CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877424/444991), which doesn't contain a function in another, which I think would work:

```
function event_exists(eventName){
    if(typeof(eventName)!='string' || eventName.length==0)return false;
    var TAGNAMES = {
        'select':'input','change':'input',
        'submit':'form','reset':'form',
        'error':'img','load':'img','abort':'img'
    }
    var el = document.createElement(TAGNAMES[eventName] || 'div');
    eventName = 'on' + eventName;
    var isSupported = (eventName in el);
    if (!isSupported) {
        el.setAttribute(eventName,'return;');
        isSupported = (typeof(el[eventName])=='function');
    }
    el = null;
    return isSupported;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a new element?  What's wrong with just doing a simple `typeof` check on the event class?  (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69890629))

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to just do a `typeof` check on the event class.

For example: `typeof(InputEvent)` returns `"function"` in Chrome and `"undefined"` in Internet Explorer.