# In JavaScript DOM, can it be determined if an element will listen for an event type?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Detecting support for a given JavaScript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877393/detecting-support-for-a-given-javascript-event)

having a random HTMLElement `el`, is there anyway of knowing whether `el` can listen to an particular event type, for example, 'change'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try checking if `el.attributes.onchange` is declared. I'm not sure, however, if dynamic changes to the webpage will be visible in this manner.

Comment: there is a property `el.onchange` == `null`, meaning it can be there, as versus `el.onchangexxx` == `undefined`, meaning it won't happen.  the problem is that even DIV's have `onchange==null`, so this does not help anything.

Comment: @cc young, keep in mind that the [change event bubbles](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents), which means that a DIV can _listen_ for a change event that is triggered by one of its children.  If you're asking how to detect whether an element can _trigger_ an event, that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check it for a truthy value like this:

```
if (el.change) {
    el.change();
}
```

If the method exists you will be able to call it like this.  You can check for any method in the manor before trying to call it.

Comment: what if the change trigger has not yet been instantiated?  what I'm trying to find is if I _can_ add a change trigger, ie, that is is a form element.