# Why does `'onhashchange' in window` return `true` in IE7 compat mode of IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, graceful-degradation

I want to check if the browser supports `hashchange` event and, if not, fake it with `setInterval`.

I have tried

```
if ('onhashchange' in window) {
    window.onhashchange = hashChange;
} else {
    /* setInterval graceful degradation */
}
```

But the problem is that, in IE8 in IE7 Compat mode, `'onhashchange' in window` returns `true` because `window.onhashchange` is `null` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCP8Y/))

Why does it happen? If I use `'onclick2' in window`, it returns `false`!

I have read [Detecting support for a given JavaScript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877393/detecting-support-for-a-given-javascript-event), but I would prefer to use something simpler if possible.

Comment: "IE8 in IE7 mode": could the mode functionality be including more recent developments as well, on top of behaving like IE7?

Comment: @mavili I have no idea, but `hashchange` event doesn't work on IE8 in IE7 mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `'onhashchange' in window` was `true` because I was using IE8 in IE7 mode instead of real IE7

But I have just tried it with [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and `'onhashchange' in window` gives `false`.

Now, I wonder why does IE 8 have IE7 mode if it can't emulate IE7 very well

Comment: The point is that it emulates the older version *well enough*. Compatibility View was never perfect (nor was it designed to be) and the IE team is continuing to move away from that technology with IE11.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why IE is giving you that, but why not just test for true

```
if(("onhashchange" in window) === true){
  /* Supported */
}else{
  /* Backup */
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is that `'onhashchange' in window` gives `true`